# returning xmlhttp responseText from function as return

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

im new in javascript and php , my goal is :RETURN string from xmlhttp responseText to a function return value.So i can use it with innerText or innerHTML method.
the html code :

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(myurl){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
              xmlhttp.responseText;}
     }

    xmlhttp.open("GET",myurl,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `innerText`: it's a Microsoft proprietary member, and although is supported by Chrome it isn't by Firefox for example. Use it as a fallback if `textContent` isn't supported (IE8 and older).

Answer (score 11):

You can't.

Neither runs the code syncronous, nor would you `return` anything to `loadXMLDoc` but to the anonymous function which is the *onreadystatechange* handler.

Your best shot is to pass a callback function.

```
function loadXMLDoc(myurl, cb) 
{
   // Fallback to Microsoft.XMLHTTP if XMLHttpRequest does not exist.
   var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            if (typeof cb === 'function') cb(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }

   xhr.open("GET", myurl, true);
   xhr.send();

}
```

And then call it like

```
loadXMLDoc('/foobar.php', function(responseText) {
    // do something with the responseText here
});
```

Comment: to jAndy: iwant loadXMLdoc function it self as returing value so i can make simple function to   set innerText or innerHTML in element, can this possible?

Comment: @inogbox: not as long as your ajax request runs in asynronous mode (which is highly recommendable). You can manually set the request to *sync*, which would mean that it will lock down and freeze the browser-UI everytime the request is running. You could do that by setting the third paremeter of `.open()` to `false`.

Comment: my goal is using asynronous mode, so i must create handler to pass the response text?

Comment: why your code cannot run? even im using alert() function when i call it does't return anything

Comment: @inogbox: my code won't run ? Anyway - there is **no way** to return anything in that constelation and an asyncronous request. You have to either choose between a synced request or using the callback-method like I demonstrated.

Comment: yes i copy and paste your code in my code editor and also i create function to execute loadXMLDoc, and i put alert() function in '//do something with the responseText here', nothing happen, the message box i expected not showing can you tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Just return the responseText property or assign its value to a variable in closure.

Returning a value:

```
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc(myurl) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                return xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", myurl, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return xmlhttp.onreadystatechange();
    }
</script>
```

Using a closure:

```
<script>
    var myValue = "",
        loadXMLDoc = function (myurl) {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    return xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET", myurl, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            myValue = xmlhttp.onreadystatechange();
        };
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in asynchronous mode.

Comment: If it demands a function reference to invoke the call then it should not be asynchronous to anything except perhaps the other contents of the local function.

Comment: What do you mean? This request is asynchronous, so `return` will not return the actual response, because it has not been received yet.

Comment: No, its not. This is how I use AJAX in my own software at http://prettydiff.com/  Nothing in JavaScript is asynchronous.  It is variant external access to JavaScript that creates the appearance of asynchronous operation.

Comment: You really have to use synchronous mode for ajax (`.open(..., false)`) or else `return` is bogus. See your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/HApG3/.