# Wait for return from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got that piece of code:

```
var result;

$.when(result=make_req("GET", "ajax.php?request=opendiv", true, null, null)).done(alert(result));
```

Can you tell me, why does alert show 'undefined'?

make_req() makes some ajax call, it works properly and returns good value when I call it alone.

I want to store results from make_req in the variable 'result' and then use it.

Comment: Can you show us your `make_req` function, please?

Comment: Make sure to have read [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi http://jsfiddle.net/7Lfy2d8y/

Comment: You really should use `$.ajax` instead.

Comment: It must be a solution to do this in this way...

Comment: Here we go!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421860/returning-xmlhttp-responsetext-from-function-as-return

Comment: No, it's impossible. Have you read the question I've linked, and all of it's answers? Your new question just asks for the very same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You're executing the alert right away, you're not waiting for the result

You have to reference a function, not call it, and adding the parenthesis to a function will call it, in this case you can use an anonymous function instead, and call alert inside that

```
$.when( make_req("GET", "ajax.php?request=opendiv", true, null, null) )
   .done(function(result) {
        alert(result);
});
```

Of course, `make_req()` has to return a deferred promise!

Comment: Whoa, that answer wasn't there when I started mine. I didn't get the notification. Sorry for the identical answer - quite right that you get the upvotes for being the early bird.

Comment: @Utkanos - No problem, happens to me all the time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because `done()` expects a callback function to be passed as its only parameter, whereas you are passing the return value of `alert`. You need:

```
.done(function(result) { alert(result); });
```